# Android - Retrieving data from SMS ContentProvider - GROUP BY

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm working on a SMS application and I faced some problems retrieving the data from the ContentProvider using the GROUP BY clause.

I have read a lot of threads of similar questions, but they still do not provide a working solution for me.

What I want, is to get the most recent SMS from every thread. To achive this I have to select the maximum value of DATE column, and group it by THREAD_ID, I believe.

Suppose the SMS table looks like this:

```
============================
THREAD_ID | MESSAGE | DATE |  
============================
1         | Hello   | 555                    
1         | Hi      | 666
2         | Test    | 333
2         | Test 2  | 999
```

And the result should return the:

```
1 - Hi - 666
2 - Test 2 999
```

This is what I have so far, but the below code retrieves the most recent SMS from the whole table, not from specific category. It look like the GROUP BY clause is neglected.

```
    String CONTENT_URI = "content://sms/";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI);

    String selection = "date=(SELECT max(date) FROM sms )";
    selection+=") GROUP BY (thread_id";
    Cursor c = managedQuery(uri, null, selection, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            textView.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Column.THREAD_ID))
                    + " - " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Column.ADDRESS))
                    + " - " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Column.READ))
                    + " - " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Column.BODY))
                    + " - " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Column.DATE))
                    + "\n");

        }
        c.close();
    } else {
        textView.setText("Cursor is null");
    }
```

Thank you in advance, I would appreciate very much if you could help me find a solution for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GROUP BY clause is neglected because SELECT give only 1 value (in your code).

I don't know very well SQL but I think this should work (sry, I don't know exact syntax)

```
SELECT thread, message, MAX(date)
FROM sms
GROUP BY thread
```

Answer (score 0):

use a library like CPH [here](https://github.com/jenzz/ContentProviderHelper) to do all the boilerplate stuff for you. The example code shows all the query stuff that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Implement as following

[public Cursor query (SQLiteDatabase db, String[] projectionIn, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String sortOrder)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String))

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
/* a String is a Object, so it can be null!*/
String groupBy = null;
String having = null;

switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
...
...
...
    case EPISODES_NEXT:
    groupBy = "ShowID";
    queryBuilder.setTables(EpisodenTable.TableName);
    break;
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
}

Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
        groupBy, having, sortOrder);
c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
return c;
```

}